# Vue, base-input label gets placeholder

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Can someone help me debug this?

I have a BaseInput and BaseTextarea components.

I'm attaching attribute placeholder to the input and textarea accordingly. Rest of attributes goes to label.

In BaseTextarea everything is fine, but in BaseInput not only input gots placeholder but also label gets it.

BaseTextarea label:

[image]

BaseInput label:

[image]

Why is this happening?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/71w31l80w0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your BaseInput: you don't specify "inheritAttrs: false" (label is the root element of the component that inherits props)

Comment: That's the missed part. Thank you! I spend half a day because of this. Sometimes it is better to copy & paste; P

Comment: Or use mixins, factory functions and other design patterns to reduce the copy/paste and the overlap of concepts :P Good luck dude, abstracting forms is always a challenge!